# Completion ports (limits)

Tags: iocp

I have some questions about Completion ports:

1. How many Completion ports could be opened at the same time per process?
2. What pros and cons of separating ports by data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) why not write a test to see. Chances are that it will be a) more than you could ever need, b) platform and memory specific and c) not a useful number to know.

2) define "by data type". In general your aim should be to have as few threads running as possible and having more than one IOCP means that you either have more threads running (or able to run) than you would have with a single IOCP OR you have the same number of threads and they are used less efficiently as some completions cause some threads to wake and run and others cause a different set of threads to wake and run.

In general I'd need to know more about what you ACTUALLY want to do to be able to provide a more useful answer.